# Saving new django model object gives duplicate key

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-postgresql

Django 2.2.3 on Python 3.7, with Amazon RDS Postgres Database.

Saving a new object doesn't work for this Company model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

```
comp = Company(name='test')
comp.save()
```

Gives

```
UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "appname_company_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(29) already exists
```

I can confirm that yes, there is an entry with id=29 in the table.

Why is Django trying to use that as the ID, and how do I stop it?

Comment: Post your `Company` model please. By the way, the correct way to instantiate a model instance is `Company.objects.create(name='test')` (you don't need to `.save()` if you use this).

Comment: Added `Company` model. Yes you are correct about the instantiation, but it gives the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked it out.

The [Django Import/Export app](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) doesn't reset any sequences after importing. This means that any additions in any tables in which data was imported will fail.

The solution is the following:

```
python manage.py sqlsequencereset <your app name> | python manage.py dbshell
```

This generates and runs SQL like this:

```
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"appname_company"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "appname_company";
```