# Django : Error: 'duplicate key value violates unique constraint'

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have to save images with s3 when creating a new object for my website.

I have a code to save my images that I use in my model's save method.

When I use the django administration panel, I can easily create my object without any error.

It also works well when I send my data without adding an image.

But when I try to create my object throught my view, I get this error : `Error: 'duplicate key value violates unique constraint « store_shop_pkey »' DETAIL: key (id)=(37) already exists`

I think that in my serializer's create method, I try to save my object twice : once for the image and once for the rest of my object's keys.

I don't know how to resolve this issue.

It works well with PUT method.

Here is my code :

**models.py :**

```
class Shop(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(ShopCategory, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, null=True, blank=True) # Set a null and blank = True for serializer
    mustBeLogged = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    deliveries = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0),], default=7)
    message = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    banner = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            """If we want to update"""
            this = Shop.objects.get(id=self.id)
            if self.banner:
                image_resize(self.banner, 300, 300)
                if this.banner != self.banner:
                    this.banner.delete(save=False)
            else:
                this.banner.delete(save=False)
        except:
            """If we want to create a shop"""
            if self.banner:
                image_resize(self.banner, 300, 300)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self):
        self.banner.delete(save=False)
        super().delete()
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**utils.py :**

```
def image_resize(image, width, height):
    # Open the image using Pillow
    img = Image.open(image)
    # check if either the width or height is greater than the max
    if img.width > width or img.height > height:
        output_size = (width, height)
        # Create a new resized “thumbnail” version of the image with Pillow
        img.thumbnail(output_size)
        # Find the file name of the image
        img_filename = Path(image.file.name).name
        # Spilt the filename on “.” to get the file extension only
        img_suffix = Path(image.file.name).name.split(".")[-1]
        # Use the file extension to determine the file type from the image_types dictionary
        img_format = image_types[img_suffix]
        # Save the resized image into the buffer, noting the correct file type
        buffer = BytesIO()
        img.save(buffer, format=img_format)
        # Wrap the buffer in File object
        file_object = File(buffer)
        # Save the new resized file as usual, which will save to S3 using django-storages
        image.save(img_filename, file_object)
```

**views.py :**

```
class ShopList(ShopListView):
    """Create shop"""
    def post(self, request):
        """For admin to create shop"""
        serializer = MakeShopSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

**serializers.py :**

```
class MakeShopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Shop
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # validated_data.pop('path')
        path = validated_data["name"].replace(" ", "-").lower()
        path = unidecode.unidecode(path)
        unique = False
        while unique == False:
            if len(Shop.objects.filter(path=path)) == 0:
                unique = True
            else:
                # Generate a random string
                char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                path += "-{}".format("".join(random.sample(char, 5)))
        shop = Shop.objects.create(**validated_data, path=path)
        shop.save()
        return shop
    
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        #You will have path in validated_data
        #And you may have to check if the values are null
        return super(MakeShopSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
```

Finally, this is the data that I send :

[image: Data send]

Thank you by advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and this answer helped me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58533530/11326316

so try this command:

```
python manage.py sqlsequencereset <your app name> | python manage.py dbshell
```

Answer (score 0):

The next line is possible to have a problem with primary key:

`shop = Shop.objects.create(**validated_data, path=path)`

you may try to put every single attribute one by one, like this:

```
shop = Shop.objects.create(
name=validated_data['name'],
category=validated_data['category'],
...
path=path)
```

If it didn't resolve your problem, please post more about your error from terminal

Comment: I still get the same error... The full error is ```django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Error: 'duplicate key value violates unique constraint « store_shop_pkey »' DETAIL: key (id)=(37) already exists```

Comment: @Bastien please send full stack error with lines, you can upload stack track on pastebin

Answer (score 0):

Your model's unique key is `path`, so inside create function of your serializer,

`shop = Shop.objects.create(**validated_data, path=path)`, tries creating a new model.
Consider the second instance you trying to add has the same path as the previous instance, in that case, you get this error since `path` should be unique and you are trying to add another model with the same value which DBMS rejects.
One of the things you can try is,
create or update the instance. If you are fine with updating the instance when your second instance has the same path as the previous one, then use

```
Shop.objects.update_or_create(path=path,
                        defaults=validated_data)
```

else

try adding unique constraints if your model cannot stand unique just by using the `path` field.
[django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint)

Comment: I think the error comes from banner instead of path because when I send my data without the banner field, it works well. When I try to do update_or_create, I still get the same error

Comment: and trigger the same API again without passing `path` and does that still succeed?

Comment: I now get this error : ```get() returned more than one Shop -- it returned 9!```

Comment: can you share the entire error with at least 5 lines of traceback?

Comment: I put it on pastebin : https://pastebin.com/w3WfEPLy . It's without passing ```path```

Comment: Can you add the entire log, please? To the same link?

Comment: Sorry I had to create a new pastebin : https://pastebin.com/4mGLjFBG

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236317/discussion-between-jyothi-s-and-bastien).